# Connect Django to redshift database and retrieve data

Tags: django, django-models, amazon-redshift

I have connected django to redshift database with correct credentials as follows:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
},
'redshift_db': {
    'NAME': 'test',
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'USER': 'test',
    'PASSWORD': 'xxxx',
    'HOST': 'xxxxxxxx.redshift.amazonaws.com',
    'PORT': 5439
}}
```

I want to know what i should include in my models.py and how I should execute queries from my view

Comment: change you default to redshift database and if the table and columns match with the database in your local you dont have to change anything,

Comment: redshift database has a set of schemas and tables are listed under schemas. How do I connect to a particular schema? for example I have two tables named sales and customer under the schema products. 
i want to connect to the schema named 'products' and work with the tables under that

Comment: got through this link, hope you find it useful https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/multi-db/

Answer (score 1):

For your models.py file:
You can spesify db_for_read and db_for_write functions ([Routers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/multi-db/#database-routers)

For the views.py you can use ORM or cursor with spesific databases.

ORM: `YourModel.objects.using("redshift_db")...`

SQL: `from django.db import connections`and `cursor = connections["redshift_db"].cursor()`